# Custom microros agent running with ros2 nodes

Tags: ros2

I have defined a custom microros agent (custom transport) in a microros_ws folder. I have set the ros2 workspace in another folder called ros2_ws. When I run the nodes (eg. ros2 run cpp_pubsub talker) inside the ros2 folder the nodes cannot see the agent running.
How do you make the custom agent visible?

The version is ros2 iron.